# How to return all items in array that don't have their opposite?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have for example this array [-3, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2], and I'd like to return 4 because it doesn't have its own opposite. I've been struggling for several hours to understand how to implement the algorithm.
This is what I've done so far:

```
   let numbers = [-3, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2];
   let sortedNumebrs = [];

    //It returns the numbers array sorted
     function sortedArray() {
         sortedNumebrs = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
         return sortedNumebrs;
      }

      // It return an array with all positive numbers
      function positive() {
         let positive = sortedArray().filter((e) => Math.sign(e) === 1);
         return positive;
      }


      // It return an array with all negative numbers
       function negative() {
        let negative = sortedNumebrs.filter((e) => Math.sign(e) === -1);
        negative = negative.sort((a, b) => a + b);
        return negative;
       }

     // It returns the array longer
     function minLength() {
       let minNum = Math.min(positive().length, negative().length);

       if (minNum === positive().length) {
       return positive()
     } else {
       eturn negative();
    }
   }

     // It returns the array shorter
      function maxLength() {
        let maxNum = Math.max(positive().length, negative().length);
        if (maxNum === positive().length) {
        return positive()
        } else {
         return negative();
        }
       }


  // Function that should return  string if each numbers has its 
  // own opposite otherwise 4
      function opposite() {
         let result = (minLength() === maxLength()) ? true : false;
          if (result) {
         return 'Each element has own opposite';
         } else {     
           // some code
         }
       }
```

Comment: Please post your work thus far so people can better understand your thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const yourArray =[-3, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2];
const result = [];

for (let el1 of yourArray) {
  let hasOpposite = false;

  for (let el2 of yourArray) {
    if (el1 === -el2) {
      hasOpposite = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!hasOpposite) {
    result.push(el1);
  }
}

console.log(result); // [4]
```

or using array functions:

```
const yourArray = [-3, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2];
const itemsWithoutOpposite = yourArray.filter(el1 => !yourArray.includes(-el1));
```

Comment: That's true. I added a snippet which used those functions instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.  This one assumes that duplicates need matching too, so if I have [1, -1, 1] that final 1 should have an additional -1 to match, rather than using the -1 that was matched by the initial 1.  It will also not match an element with itself, so if you have a 0 you will need another zero to match.

```js
const yourArr = [-3, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2];

const result = [...yourArr];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  let el = result[i];
  let inverse = result.indexOf(-el, i + 1);
  if (inverse !== -1) {
    result.splice(inverse, 1);
    result.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```